# Como converter um "SQLite3 object cursor" para uma lista (Python)

Tags: python, sqlite3

Numa célula de uma tabela da minha base de dados tenho uma lista de pares. Tenho um módulo em Python que quero que vá buscar essa lista na base de dados e a leia como sendo uma lista. Tentei executar isto:

```
interpretation = db.execute("SELECT interpretation FROM music WHERE ID = ?", (id, ))
```

Já tentei fazer `list(interpretation)`, `eval(interpretation)`, mandar a lista para a base de dados convertida em JSON, e descodificar no módulo que vai buscar esses valores, mas nada funcionou. O problema é por isso simples: quero que a minha *interpretation*, que é interpretada como um "*SQLite3 object cursor*" seja interpretada como sendo uma lista.

Comment: Já tentaste fazer eval da variável interpretation ?

Answer (score 1):

A chamada ao método `execute` - tanto de uma conexão ao banco, quanto de um objeto cursor em Python não devolve os resultados imediatamente.
Isso é feito de propósito, de forma que fique mais fácil criar aplicações em que o banco trabalha de forma assíncrona. (Não é o caso do SQLite, que roda no mesmo processo - mas outros bancos são acionados
pela camada de rede, e podem ir retornando os valores de forma "lazy")

Para recuperar os resultados de uma query, se usam os métodos `fetch` e `fetchall` - ou você pode simplesmente usar o cursor como iterador `for`: ele vai retornando os resultados:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT interpretation FROM music WHERE ID = ?", (id, ))
for result in cursor:
   print(result)[0]
```

(no caso,,o "result" é uma tupla com os valores retornados em cada linha da query, Se a query deveria voltar 16 colunas, setá uma tupla contendo os 16 valores, com índices entre 0 e 15)

Se você desejar simplesmente jogar os valores numa estrutura de dados, como está na pergunta - é um pouco menos eficiente do que usar o `for` direto (principalmente por que você vai duplicar os dados temporariamente na memória) - deveria poder fazer simplesmente:

```
cursor = db.execute(...)
results = list(cursor)
```

como você colocou. Só que cada elemento da lista é uma tupla,
com todos os seus resultados - mesmo que você só tenha uma coluna. Então é uma tupla com um único elemento - e você pode extrai-lo com a sintaxe de list comprehension assim:

```
results = [line[0] for line in cursor]
```

Comment: Desde já obrigado pela resposta.
Se bem o entendi, sugeiru que executasse:
     results = [line[0] for line in cursor]
no entanto, após ter tentado, obtive o que obtive com as outras soluções que tentei arranjar, ou seja, algo que não é uma lista.
Posso daí depreender que a sua solução não funciona, ou terei percebido mal o que disse?

Comment: Qual versão de Python está usando?  Pode ser que numa versão mais antiga o cursor não seja interável diretamente. Use `minha_lista = cursor.fetchall()` então